pbox latex in tabular alignment with text
I wrote this code on overleaf and got something like in the picture. Is it possible to align "Contact Inofrmation" with "Department .."? What is the easiest way to do so? Thanks.
\begin{tabular}[t]{lll}
\pbox{20cm}{Contact \\ 
            Information} 
& & 
\pbox{20cm}{Department of abc \\ 
            abc University \\ 
            New abc city 00000, Country X \\ \\ 
            Email: blabla.com}
\end{tabular}



Please don't post code fragments. Instead, put your fragments into a complete compilable document that shows the problem. You should also indent code lines by 4 spaces, they'll be marked as a code sample. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Please do tell us how or where \pbox is defined.

You want \pbox[t].
In the meantime, you can also improve the typesetting, avoiding \\ \\ and also padding space on either side. Change \qquad to \hspace{<dimen>} if you want different spacing between the two columns: adding an empty column is not the correct way to do it.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{\qquad}l@{}}
\pbox[t]{20cm}{Contact \\
            Information}
&
\pbox[t]{20cm}{Department of abc \\
            abc University \\
            New abc city 00000, Country X \\[\baselineskip]
            Email: blabla.com}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}



Not knowing what \pbox means I would have to guess. It sounds like a \parbox20cm} (or p{20cm} column, but 2 columns of 20cm looks a bit too wide for me.
I suggest to use the makecell package, and use the t alignment. If you want columns of a specific witdth you can replace the l with something like p{5cm}. But in that case you could just use a p{5cm} column instead of \makecell.
Another option is to split each entry into separate lines, see second tabular.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{makecell}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tabular}{lll}
  \makecell[tl]{Contact \\ 
            Information} 
& & 
\makecell[tl]{Department of abc \\ 
            abc University \\ 
            New abc city 00000, Country X \\ \\ 
            Email: blabla.com}
\end{tabular}
\bigskip

\noindent
\begin{tabular}{lll}
  Contact     & & Department of abc \\ 
  Information & & abc University \\ 
              & & New abc city 00000, Country X \\ \\ 
              & & Email: blabla.com
\end{tabular}

\end{document}


